# C# Error Message: CS1503Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, arrays

Does anybody can help me with this issue?
I can't run this code on VS. It's displaying Cannot convert from "void" to bool.
I got stuck here and I can't run this piece of code.

Any idea about where the issue is?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;



    namespace HelloWorld
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args, Array array)
            {
                int[] newAge = { 21, 31, 41, 51, 61 };
                int[] olderAge = { 71, 81, 91, 101, 121 };
                //int i = newAge.Length;


                Console.WriteLine(Array.Copy(newAge, olderAge, 4));
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: `Array.Copy` returns void. You cannot print void

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.Copy` doesn't return anything.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int32_)  So there's nothing to write to the console.  Simply remove that `Console.WriteLine` operation:

```
Array.Copy(newAge, olderAge, 4);
```

Then the question becomes... What *do* you want to write to the console?  For example, if you want to output the contents of one of the arrays, output that:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', newAge));
```

This would join the values from `newAge` into a comma-delimited string and write that string to the console.

Comment: NOW IT WORKS!!! Thanks again!